# How can I add a Python ML trained model file to a Flutter app and retrieve the results?

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have developed a Flutter application, a voice recognition app. This app records voice within the Flutter environment and sends the recorded voice using an API call (POST method) to a Python server. The Python server contains a trained model file, and after processing, it retrieves the result to display in the Flutter app. However, the processing speed depends on the internet connection. I'd like to know if it's possible to add the trained model file to the Flutter assets folder. Also, for sending voice to the trained model file, can I pass the voice directly using some functions, or do I need to use API calls as previously mentioned? I've come across scenarios where this can be done using the TensorFlow Lite plugin, but I have no idea how to implement it. Could you please clarify what is possible and what is not, and provide guidance on the feasible way? If you have any documentation on this, please share it

Comment: Yes you can use tensorflow or google ml packages. Yes you can add your python trained ml file to assets. As far as I remember, that ml file has to have tflite extension. You can follow many articles or videos on how to implement ml kit or tensorflow but I do not know if it supports voice. I have worked with image, face, text, ocr with ml kits before.